# Troubles creating tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ddl

I'm trying to make two tables execute but I keep getting errors on them. Transaction table says it can't execute without the other being created and then I try to create the broker table and it says missing right parenthesis

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

but I checked my code and it looks well. Would any of you know what is the problem? thanks to all who comment!

```
    Create table Broker
(
    Broker_Number Number(7,0)
      Constraint PK_Broker_Broker_Number Primary Key
      Constraint NN_Broker_Broker_Number Not Null,
   First_Name Varchar2(25)
      Constraint NN_Broker_First_Name Not Null,
   Last_Name Varchar2(3O)
      Constraint NN_Broker_Last_Name Not Null,
   Area_Code Number(3,0)
      Default '780'
      Constraint NL_Broker_Area_Code Null,
   Phone_Number Number(7,0)
      Constraint NL_Broker_Phone_Number Null,
   Email_Address Varchar2(50)
      Constraint CK_Broker_Email_Address Check (REGEXP_like(Email_Address,'%@%.%'))
      Constraint NN_Broker_Email_Address Not Null
);


Create table Transaction
(
  Portfolio_Number Number(7,0) Not Null,
      Constraint FK_Trans_Portfolio_Number
      Foreign Key (Portfolio_Number)
      References Portfolio(Portfolio_Number),
  Stock_Code Varchar2(10) Not Null,
      Constraint FK_Transaction_Stock_Code
      Foreign Key (Stock_Code)
      References Stock(Stock_Code),
  Transaction_Date Date
      Constraint PK_Trans_Transaction_Date Not Null,
  Exchange_Code Varchar2(4) Not Null,    
      Constraint FK_Transaction_Exchange_Code
      Foreign Key (Exchange_Code)
      References Exchange(Exchange_Code),
  Broker_Number Number(7,0) Not Null,
      Constraint FK_Transaction_Broker_Number
      Foreign Key (Broker_Number)
      References Broker(Broker_Number),
  Buy_Sell Char(1)
      Constraint CK_Transaction_Buy_Sell Check (Buy_Sell in ('B','S') )
      Constraint NN_Transaction_Buy_Sell Not Null,
  Quantity Number(7,0)
      Constraint NN_Transaction_Quantity Not Null,
  Price_Per_Share Number(6,2)
      Constraint NN_Transaction_Price_Per_Share Not Null
)
```

Comment: Don't know PL/SQL terribly well, but `TRANSACTION` is a keyword in every flavor of SQL that I'm familiar with, including PL/SQL. I suspect that you can't have a table named `Transaction` unless you enclose it in brackets or something, and even then I think it's a bad idea. [Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/transact.htm) some doc.

Comment: i tried adding brackets but couldnt figure it out it diddnt work. and i need to figure out why it gives the error and ive tried everything

Comment: I suggest you change the name of your table to something else and see what happens.

Comment: @BobRodes i cannot create the transaction table no matter the name because it needs a column from the broker table but the broker table cant be made because it has an error i dont know how to fix

Comment: @mohammedtarrabain: SQL requires double quotes if you want to use reserved keywords as identifiers, e.g.: `"transaction"` but note that the name is then case **sensitive**. `"Transaction"` is a different name than `"TRANSACTION"` or `"transaction"`. For details see the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this line

> Last_Name Varchar2(3O)

That's not 30, it is 3O, as in the letter O after the number three.

One way to debug such error statements is to remove one column at a time, run the statement, and repeat the process until you don't encounter the error any more. In this case, I deleted this specific line and it worked fine. That's when I noticed the O instead of 0 in the editor.

Comment: Good catch. :) I might have looked for that myself, but got caught up on Transaction being a keyword.